# C# Winforms Irregular Windows

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

How do I create windows with irregular shapes using WinForms and C#?

Comment: What is your definition of irregular?

Comment: I'm guessing without the regular WinForm look with the titlebar, borders, etc.?

Comment: no irregular windows like some windows media player skins that we have seen , get the point not rectangular or rounded edges.

Comment: this should be closed because is a dupe as Nifle pointed.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few different ways to achieve this. One is use use `TransparencyKey` (as in the post pointed out by Nifle). Another one is to assign a [`Region`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.region.aspx) object to the [`Region`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.region.aspx) property of the form:

```
System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath path = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
path.AddPolygon(new[]
{
    new Point(20, 20),
    new Point(40, 10),
    new Point(180, 70),
    new Point(160, 260),
    new Point(80, 140)
});
path.AddEllipse(40, 40, 300, 300);
this.Region = new Region(path);
```

Note that the coordinates refer to the window, not the client area. Also note how overlapping figures in the `GraphicsPath` object "invert" each other by default (this can be prevented by setting `path.FillMode = FillMode.Winding`).