# How to make form rounded rectangle or round or triangle

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I am developing an application in C# and there is a requirement of the form of the main window in rounded rectangle or some times triangle type or round shape.
so, how can I achieve this kind of features in C# 2008

Comment: yes this is windows form

Comment: Duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326673/c-winforms-irregular-windows

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

http://www.codersource.net/csharp_custom_window_forms.aspx

Also you can google for it, there are plenty examples.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is on Windows Forms you can check these two articles on MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289517(VS.71).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984331(VS.71).aspx

You basically have to do the following:

- Remove the form border by setting its style to None
- Set a background image that defines the shape of your form
- Set the TransparencyKey of the form to the color that should be transparent

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Region property of your form.  You can create a new Region, set its shape using it's various Add... methods and then assign the region to your form's region property.