# C# - Create a styled winforms like in Windows 7

Tags: c#, winforms, customization, system-tray

I would like to create a winform like this:

[image: Winform styled like a popup from notification area (Windows 7)]

I already accomplished the visual effect (like as seen in the picture), by [following other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2169006). But I can't disallow resizing the form, since to have the border, it must be "Sizeable". Someone suggested putting Minimum Size and Maximum Size values equal to the current Form Size. This solves part of the issue, but when the mouse hovers the border, it still shows the double-ended arrow, suggesting the form is resizeable. Is there any way of disable this cursor change? My goal is to mimic the original systray popups in Windows 7, like the network, sound, etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a message handler to your form and handle WM_NCHITTEST. When the original returns HTSIZE (etc.), return HTNONE or HTCAPTION.

Something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30184/winforms-click-drag-anywhere-in-the-form-to-move-it-as-if-clicked-in-the-form) should get you started.

To explain:

When Windows wants to know which cursor to use for your window, it first sends you a `WM_NCHITTEST` message (non-client hit test). This message is handled by the `WndProc` method. Your window is supposed to return one of the `HT*` codes to tell Windows which part of the window the mouse is over. For example, return `HTCAPTION` for the caption area, `HTCLIENT` for the client area, or `HTSIZENESW` for the bottom left sizing corner. The default message handler (calling `base.WndProc`) deals with this for standard windows.

We don't have a standard window.

What we're trying to do here is ask the original window what the mouse is over. If it returns any of the `HTSIZE*` values, we want to replace that return value with `HTNONE` (for no action) or `HTCLIENT` (if you want the cursor to be treated as inside the window -- probably not this one) or `HTCAPTION` (if you want to be able to drag the window by the edges -- might be useful).

Comment: I changed the example you gave me (instead of HTCLIENT, I put HTSIZE (0x4)), but the cursor still changes. Sorry, I'm new to WndProc, and I'm not sure what I'm doing. If possible, can you provide some example for this case?

Comment: Thanks, it worked great after some research. For constants, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645618%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Example code:

```
private const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84;
private const int HTCLIENT = 0x1;

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    switch (m.Msg)
    {
        case WM_NCHITTEST:
            m.Result = (IntPtr)HTCLIENT;
            return;
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

This way, when the cursor hovers the borders, the pointer doesn't change, because it's treated as if it was inside the form, achieving the desired effect.