# How can I get a window to look like a frame?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, trayicon, window-style

It should look like the little box that appears when you click the Action Center, Power, Network, or Sound icon in the tray. It needs to have that glass border without the title bar.

[image]

It also needs to be a fixed size and not resizable. Thanks to anyone who can help! :)

Comment: A few seconds of googling should give you the answer. Disable the Maximise, Minimse and Control boxes, set the title to empty string and set the form `FormBorderStyle` to `Fixed3D`

Comment: This doesn't give me a glass-like border... It does work when I set the border to Sizable but it has to be fixed size.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a System-tray styled box in Winforms (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169006/create-a-system-tray-styled-box-in-winforms-c)

Comment: @FactorMystic That is not an exact duplicate.  The accepted answer in that question is resizable, which is not what Phoenix is looking for.

Comment: No but to be fair the difference between the 2 is a single property...

Comment: @Basic As you can see from my answer it is a little more than a single property to get the correct look and feel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the ControlBox to false, clear the title text, and set the border style.  Since you stated you want the sizable border, but not allow it to be resized, you can set the min and max size as well. Finally to prevent the mouse cursor from showing the resize cursor, we override the [WM_NCHITTEST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645618%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) result if they are on one of the borders:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ControlBox = false;
    this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
    this.MinimumSize = this.MaximumSize = this.Size; 
    this.Text = "";                
}
const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084;
const int HTBOTTOM = 15;
const int HTBOTTOMLEFT = 16;
const int HTBOTTOMRIGHT = 17;
const int HTLEFT = 10;
const int HTRIGHT = 11;
const int HTTOPLEFT = 13;
const int HTTOPRIGHT = 14;
const int HTTOP = 12;
const int HTCLIENT = 1;
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(ref m);
    if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(m.Result.ToString());
        switch (m.Result.ToInt32())
        {
            case HTBOTTOM:
            case HTBOTTOMLEFT:
            case HTBOTTOMRIGHT:
            case HTLEFT:
            case HTRIGHT:
            case HTTOPLEFT:
            case HTTOPRIGHT:
            case HTTOP:
                m.Result =(IntPtr) HTCLIENT;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It needs to look like glass. I'm trying to match the style of Windows 7.

Comment: @PhoenixLogan I updated the sample.  It may take some work to get rid of the resize mouse cursor, but this should give you the look and feel you want.

Comment: How would I get rid of the mouse cursor?

Comment: Never mind. I found a sample that uses an override of WndProc to handle WM_NCHITTEST and return CLIENT for all the borders.

Comment: @PhoenixLogan I found that as well and have updated the answer with a solution that worked for me.